# CPLEX library path error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, path, cplex, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm using eclipse for java coding

I completed the code and it worked well on CPLEX library 12.6(I added library in properties> libraries > add external jars > cplex.jar)

I wanted to change the library of CPLEX 12.7, so I removed previous one and added cplex.jar of CPLEX 12.7, but suddenly I got error message.

It says as below;

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no cplex1270 in java.library.path
java.library.path must point to the directory containing the CPLEX shared 
library
try invoking java with java -Djava.library.path=...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX([I)J
    at ilog.cplex.Cplex.CPXopenCPLEX(Native Method)
    at ilog.cplex.CplexI.init(CplexI.java:6736)
    at ilog.cplex.CplexI.<init>(CplexI.java:746)
    at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.<init>(IloCplex.java:10303)
    at ilog.cplex.IloCplex.<init>(IloCplex.java:10318)
    at ColumnGen$MasterProblem.createModel(ColumnGen.java:222)
    at ColumnGen$MasterProblem.<init>(ColumnGen.java:196)
    at ColumnGen.<init>(ColumnGen.java:648)
    at main_BnP_MU.<clinit>(main_BnP_MU.java:8)
```

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace contains `(Native Method)`: probably you missed to specify the native library location, the location of the *.dll* (Windows) or *.so* (Linux) file:

1. In the project properties dialog, go to *Java Build Path > Libraries*
2. Expand the CPLEX 12.7 JAR node
3. Select the subnode *Native library location: (None)* and click *Edit...*

Comment: You have to enter the location of the native library (Windows: *.dll, Linux: *.so file)

Comment: For Windows, I entered `C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio128\cplex\bin\x64_win64` and it worked.