# Cplex Java Library set up path problem in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, path, cplex

I have a newbie problem with taking the Cplex library in Eclipse,

Error: Could not find or load main class Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\bin\x64_win64
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\bin\x64_win64

I added cplex.jar from external libraries and also added the native path by editing it,
[CPLEX library path error in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45453380/cplex-library-path-error-in-eclipse)

under VMArguments I added,
-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\bin\x64_win64

where cplex12100.dll stands. I managed to work with it before but I couldn't find why it is not working right now.

Everything is 64bit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your error message references the following path:

> Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\bin\x64_win64

Notice that it does *not* start with "C:Program Files". My guess is that you need to put quotes around the path you are providing, like so:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1210\cplex\bin\x64_win64"
```

This should allow Java to handle your path which includes a space character.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the answer,
Unfortunately, I forgot to add that I already tried that, but it gives another error when I try like that.

Error: Unable to initialize main class model(my package name).model(my class name)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ilog/concert/IloException

Here is part of my code, I cut half of it(after ...) since I guess it is unrelated to the question.

```
package model;
import ilog.concert.*;
import ilog.cplex.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class model {




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


     long startTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();

     int a = 45; //matrisin boyutu
     int b = 45; //matrisin 2. boyutu
     int maxdistance = 90; //mesela 90 dan küçük deðerler
     int depot = 0;
     double alfa = 0.9;
     double beta = 0.1;
     float[][] distance = new float[a][b]; // bunu scanner dan çektik

     int m = 3;
     int C = 1200;

     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("m : " + m + "      C : " + C );
     System.out.println();

     ArrayList<ArrayList> Nlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

     Scanner reader = null;
     File burdurData = new File("burdur45.txt");

    ...


    try {

        long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;

        System.out.println("Execution time in milliseconds: " + timeElapsed);
        System.out.println("Execution time in seconds: " + timeElapsed/1000);



        } // try'ýn parantezi

    catch (IloException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
        System.out.println("sýkýntý");
    }



   }

}
```

Comment: Rather than responding with an "answer", you should *edit* your question. You might even consider asking a new question; one issue was fixed, now you have a different one. With that said, it sounds like you need to fix the path to `cplex.jar`, which should be specified with the `-classpath` option.

Comment: @baris I have your same issue (Caused by: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ilog/concert/IloException`)..did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

surely you should edit your question. In fact, for getting error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ilog/concert/IloException

I had this error before and I solved it just by importing **cplex.jar** in **ClassPath** section of my project Java Build Path not in **ModulePath**. Also set Native Library Location path to cplex's dlls folder too. Furthermore you can check your details in *java configuration->show command line* too.